# Quickbooks Online API, How to Post Negative Journal Items

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am posting data to QBO API from my system, and all transactions are posted to as a `JournalEntry`. In normal accounting it is common to post negative journal entries, but when I attempt to do that through the API, I get `Error 2290`, `Negative amount not supported on transaction line`. How can I bypass this as it seems like a very common use case?

You can reproduce the error from the QBO API here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/journalentry

```
{
  "Line": [
    {
      "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
        "PostingType": "Debit", 
        "AccountRef": {
          "name": "Opening Bal Equity", 
          "value": "39"
        }
      }, 
      "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", 
      "Amount": "-100.0", 
      "Id": "0", 
      "Description": "nov portion of rider insurance"
    }, 
    {
      "JournalEntryLineDetail": {
        "PostingType": "Credit", 
        "AccountRef": {
          "name": "Notes Payable", 
          "value": "44"
        }
      }, 
      "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", 
      "Amount": 100.0, 
      "Description": "nov portion of rider insurance"
    }
  ]
}
```

The error:

```
{
 "responseHeader": {
  "status": 400,
  "message": "",
  "intuitTid": "1-653f9b94-4d7cf9f5129c893b74025b8c",
  "realmID": "4620816365234297530"
 },
 "response": {
  "Fault": {
   "Error": [
    {
     "Message": "Amount is invalid",
     "Detail": "Negative amount -100 not supported on a transaction line",
     "code": "2290",
     "element": "Line.Amount"
    }
   ],
   "type": "ValidationFault"
  },
  "time": "2023-10-30T05:03:32.257-07:00"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer because I have not found a different solution, and after manually going to my QBO dev account and posting a negative Journal Entry, here is what happens.

I am creating a Journal Entry in Quickbooks that has 4 line items that are all negative. The accounts I use are "Undeposited Funds" for the Credits and "Prepaid Expenses" for the Debits.

[image: image showing negative journal entries]

Then, when I click "Save" at the bottom, the values are updated in the Quickbooks Journal Entry to show that the negative Credits for "Undeposited Funds" are now positive Debits and vice-versa for "Prepaid Expenses".

[image: image showing swap of debit and credit]

So what is apparent here is that in Quickbooks Online, for whatever reason, negative Journal Entries are posted as swapped Debit/Credit entries.

This seems off to me as nearly every accounting team I have spoken with needs negative journal entries, not just swapped credit/debits (although I suppose it equates to the same total). I think this is the only way with Quickbooks Online though.